# How to store JSON data using GORM to MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, json, grails, grails-orm

I have a dynamic object I need to persist whose definition and values change according to different users. You can think of them as dynamic forms which admin first defines and later is filled up by different users.

I do not have any alternative than MySQL for my project so schema-less db is out of question.

I could have done it using normal relational model storing fields and there values on multiple table but it felt too clumsy. So I decided to store those dynamic objects as JSON on MySQL table.

Is this a good approach ? If not can you suggest any proper alternatives?

In any case I am having problem retrieving the object as JSON from the database using Grails. This is my sample class where definition is the field where JSON needs to be stored.

```
String subJobType
String definition

static constraints = {
    definition nullable: false
}

static mapping = {
    definition sqlType: 'MEDIUMTEXT',type: 'text'
}
```

I can only retrieve the definition field as a string but want to return a object instead.

I could first fetch all the objects and then convert all definition field of each object to JSON but that doesn't sound a good idea.

Comment: You could use `transient` property(could be object) in domain class and a private method for that property converted from your `definition`. If you go this way you'll have a ready JSON object within your domain object

Comment: will this be reflected in my GORM queries as well ?? I mean when i call domain.getall() will i get the transient property as well ??? I tried but couldn't get the transient property in result.

Comment: No you can't issue query on transient properties. But If you have list of objects or single object, you can access the transient properties. See example how to use it: http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/transients.html

Comment: @PrakashJoshi , check this : https://dzone.com/articles/mysql-57-introduces-a-json-data-type?edition=166474&utm_source=Spotlight&utm_medium=email&utm_content=queue&utm_campaign=database%202016-05-06

Comment: I am right now in a similar scebario. Did you find an optimal solution?